# How to use gem 'geokit' to validate zipcode with respect to city and state in rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to use `gem 'geokit'` as my requirement is to validate my ***zipcode on the basis of city and province/state***. Please guide me how to use it. I had tried my own validation in my model but it don't work for me. Please help me out. I got stuck with this issue from last 15 days not getting a way.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I had tried using this http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/08/21/zipcode-validation-using-geokit-in-rails/

Comment: how did you read that code :/ please update question with formatted code. so we can see what you did there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'geokit'

geo = GeoKit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.multi_geocoder('90210')
if geo.success
  geo.state # => CA
  geo.city  # => Beverly Hills
end
```

Or you can use:

A more lightweight option is the [Area gem](http://jonathanvingiano.com/area).

```rb
require 'area'

'11211'.to_region #=> "Brooklyn, NY"
```

Comment: I have used the same code of geokit but its giving me error `uninitialized constant AccountDetail::GeoKit` I had define in model `require 'geokit'` and after that a method `def match_zip geo = geoKit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.multi_geocoder('90210')
if geo.success
  geo.state # => CA
  geo.city  # => Beverly Hills
end
end`

Comment: I had tried using require 'geokit' require 'GeoKit' and require 'Geokit' but non eof it work out. Its just rediculous its not at all working

Comment: try to `require 'openssl'` before requiring `require 'geokit'` see the edit

Comment: oh okayyyy. i got your issue. replace `GeoKit` with `Geokit`.

Comment: Facing this issue `undefined method 'multi_geocoder' for Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder:Class`

Comment: @Dinsh i dont know why you accepted dinshaw_raje's answer while i gave it 4hours before she copied my same answer

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
require 'openssl'
require 'geokit'

geo = GeoKit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode('90210')
geo.city
geo.state
```